# Establecer valor por defecto a un @Input() en Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

Tengo un **componente hijo** al cual debo pasar varios datos, los cuales recibe el componente hijo mediante [@Input()](https://angular.io/api/core/Input). Me gustaría saber **cómo asignar valores por defecto** a estos atributos, de modo que no haga falta que le pase todos los atributos si estos coinciden con los valores por defecto.

**Ejemplo:**
Si el componente hijo recibe: `@Input() disabled: boolean;` ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que si no le paso nada al componente este tenga el valor false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este tema es bien interesante, para mostrar como funciona se va a mostrar en los ejemplos el uso de dos lifecycle hooks(ciclos de vida de un componente).

Cuando se asigna un valor por defecto a un **@Input** este valor se asigna cuando no se inyecta el valor desde otro componente.

Ahora vamos a ver algun codigo que muestre esta situacion en accion.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'componenteEjemplo',
})
export class ComponenteEjemplo implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input() propiedad: boolean = false;

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    console.log('Cambio en el valor', changes.propiedad.currentValue, changes.propiedad.previousValue);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Valor al inicializar', this.propiedad);
  }

}
```

**Escenario 1:**

Componente es usado en el html sin el uso de la propiedad.

```
<componente-ejemplo></componente-ejemplo>
```

Resultado: En la consola veremos **Valor al inicializar: false**

Esto dice que onChange no fue activado. Init fue activado y se obtuvo el resultado esperado.

**Escenario 2:**

Componente usado inyectando el valor en el html.

```
<componente-ejemplo  [propiedad]="true"></componente-ejemplo>
```

Resultado:

En la consola vamos a ver algo asi,

> Cambio en el valor:true, undefined.
>
> Valor al inicializar: true

Aca vamos a ver un comportamiento distinto y es que el primer evento en ejecutar es onChange, y esto agrega el valor true y el valor previo es undefined. Solo despues que esta asignacion sucede Init es ejecutado y obtiene el valor true asignado en el evento onChange.

Espero esta solucion le ayude.